# Is this a composite sentence?

Tags: logic

*The following question is ***not*** on my homework. It is a conceptual question that followed when I saw the definition of composite sentences in a chapter on mathematical reasoning.*

A sentence such as:

> Antarctica lies to the south of the Indian Ocean and the Indian Ocean lies to the south of India.

is a composite sentence, but is such a sentence:

> It is entirely untrue that milk is an element.

a composite sentence?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, 'It is false that' is simply negation: "Books are **not** made ..."

Comment: Then, is it true that the negated sentences are composite sentences?

Comment: You have to check the def of *composite* sentence; but presumably is a sentence using a propositional connective, like "and", "or", "not",

Comment: My definition is the same as the one you presented, then the negated sentence is a composite sentence.

Comment: But no one will utter a sentence like "It is entirely untrue that..." Where does this example come from?

Comment: The example doesn't come from a textbook. It is just a hypothetical example, hence the unreal nature. 

Answer (score 0):

```
Milk is an element.
```

=> not a composite sentence.

```
Not(Milk is an element.).
```

=> not a composite sentence.

```
"Not" is just a synonym of "It is entirely untrue that".
```

Hence:

```
It is entirely untrue that milk is an element.
```

=> Why would this be a composite sentence?

Comment: The last sentence is a composite sentence because it has one sentential connective: "It is entirely untrue that".

Comment: @Mintymint: as I said, the "sentence" "It is entirely untrue that" has the same mathematical meaning than the single word "Not(...)".

Comment: The sentence "Milk is not an element" is also a composite sentence.